# UITableView and a fix header

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I have a spit view. The master is a table view. I want to put a fixed label above the table view (like a fixed header). How can I do that in the storyboard ?

Comment: Drag a view to the top of your tableView and Interface Builder will insert it as `tableViewHeader`.

Comment: Are you wanting a fixed header that stays present event when you scroll? Or as @alexburtnik said, just an overall table header?

Comment: I need a fixed header that stays when I scroll.

Answer (score 0):

In Table View Controller can't add a fixed part. But you can use a View Controller and table view in it. With this solution you can set a fixed pat at Top,Bottom or on table view.

1. First add a view controller to storyboard
2. add tableview to view controller
3. In inspector, table view > set prototype Cell = 1
4. In inspector, table view cell > set Identifier = cell
5. Add a viewcontroller.swift and write this code on it look like below

import UIKit

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var arrayTest : [String] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    arrayTest = ["iPad","iPhone","iPod","macOS","iOS"]

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

    tableView.reloadData()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return arrayTest.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = arrayTest[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

}

6. In this step your table is set to view controller and you can add view in top of the table view and add label on view.

Now you have a fixed header on top of table view. 
You can see picture of all steps in this picture. Enjoy it.
 [All image of toturial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ug78z.jpg)

Comment: That's exactly the behaviour I need ! I am going to try this asap. Thks